# How to access one component's state from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I access one component's state in another component? Below is my code and I'm trying to access the state of component `a` in component `b`.

```js
var a = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            first: "1"
        };
    },

    render: function () {
        // Render HTML here.
    }  
});

var b = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            second: a.state.first
        };
    },

    render: function () {
        // Render HTML here.
    }  
});
```

But I'm not getting anything.

Answer (score 35):

Even if you try doing this way, it is not correct method to access the `state`. Better to have a parent component whose children are `a` and `b`. The `ParentComponent` will maintain the `state` and pass it as props to the children.

For instance,

```
var ParentComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState : function() {
    return {
      first: 1,
    }
  }

  changeFirst: function(newValue) {
    this.setState({
      first: newValue,
    });
  }

  render: function() {
   return (
     <a first={this.state.first} changeFirst={this.changeFirst.bind(this)} />
     <b first={this.state.first} changeFirst={this.changeFirst.bind(this)} />
   )
 }
}
```

Now in your child compoenents `a` and `b`, access `first` variable using `this.props.first`. When you wish to change the value of `first` call `this.props.changeFirst()` function of the `ParentComponent`. This will change the value and will be thus reflected in both the children `a` and `b`.

I am writing component `a` here, `b` will be similar:

```
var a = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    var first = this.props.first; // access first anywhere using this.props.first in child
    // render JSX
  }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

If two components need access to the same state they should have a common ancestor where the state is kept.

So component A is the parent of B and C.
Component A has the state, and passes it down as props to B and C.
If you want to change the state from B you pass down a callback function as a prop.

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest you use a state manager like Redux (personal favorite), MobX reflux, etc to manage your state.

How these works is they allow you to contain all shared state in one state storage (called a store), and whatever component needs access to a part of that shared state, it will just get it from the store.

It looked very hard to get started with but once you get over the small challenges, get 2 or 3 "wtf's" out of the way. It gets easier.

Take a look here: http://redux.js.org/

**EDIT:** Redux is good but the boilerplate code is really a turn off... for those of you looking for a simpler, more magical (this can be good and bad) solution use mobx : https://mobx.js.org/

Comment: only store global data on redux/mobx store

Comment: @SibeliusSeraphini  emmm, is it true ?   Could you share more argumentation or ideas ?

Answer (score 3):

in the child component create function that sets the state:

```
changeTheState(){
    this.setState({something:"some value"})
}
```

and in parent component give the child a ref as following:

```
<Child ref={component => this._child = component}/>
```

then in parent make a function to access the changeTheState()

```
parentFunction(){
    this._child.changeTheState();
}
```

and just use the parentFunction.

Answer (score 1):

If you have A and B component where B is a child of A, you can pass a function to change the state of A though props to B.

```
function B(props) {
    return <button onClick={props.changeA} />
}

class A extends React.Component {

    //constructor
    //pass this function to B to change A's state
    handleA() {
        this.setState({});
    }

    render() {
        return <B changeA={() => this.handleA()} />
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

> Context provides a way to pass data through the component tree without having to pass props down manually at every level.

You can also [update Context from a nested component](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component) if required.