# Navigation - Pass variable to other files

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm new on React-Native and it's my first React-Native app. However, I have already some problems.

I want to pass a variable from one class (Home.js) to an another. (Is it possible without using the composent in the render() fonction ?)

```
##### Home.js #####
class Home extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {direction: "defaultvalue"};  
  }

  getCurrentDirection() {
        return this.state.direction;
    }

  render() {
  /***..... some elements ..*/
    }
}
export default Home
```

And

```
#### Two.js ####
import Home from './Home'

/** SOME CODE **/    

const DrawerOptions = {
  initialRouteName: Home.getCurrentDirection(),
  contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent,  
  drawerWidth: 300,
};
```

However it doesn't work... How to resolve it ? I have already try some solutions as declare the getCurrentDirection as static but nothing.

In addition, it seems to be a specific case because DrawerOptions is not a class. Could you please, add to your response also, how make it if I want to obtain the variable into the class Two.js ?
I meant if Two.js was for example :

```
 ##### Two.js #####
    class Two extends Component {
    var myvariable = Home.getCurrentDirection();

      render() {
      /***..... some elements ..*/
        }
    }
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recommendable way of accessing the state from a component into another is to use (in this case) the `Home` component as a parent of `Two` component. This way you don't have to trigger a function to access the `Home`'s state. On each time when the state of the parent (in this case) component will be updated, the `Two` component will receive the updated property (*direction*). If you want to call a function from `Two` component, you have to pass it a function as a property (*changeCurrentDirection*) that will call back the function you want to trigger from `Home` component.

So you would have something like this:

```js
class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      direction: "defaultValue"
    };
  }

  changeCurrentDirection() {
    this.setState({
      direction: "valueChanged"
    })
  }

  render() {
    let state = this.state;

    return (
      <Two 
        direction={state.direction}
        changeCurrentDirection={() => this.changeCurrentDirection.bind(this)}/>
    )
  }
}

class Two extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let props = this.props;
    
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>{props.direction}</h3>
        <button onClick={props.changeCurrentDirection()}>Change value</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


React.render(<Home/> , document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.0/react.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Additional info you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36837958/how-to-access-one-component-state-in-another-component).

Also, if you want to have a good management of the state of your components, my advice for you is to use [redux](http://redux.js.org/). Using this library you can easily connect the component's actions and properties that can further be accessible from other files where you can manage them.